# website lookup extremely slow in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, dns, gmail

I have a wireless broadband connection through a router and wireless modem. Everything works fine in Windows. However, in Ubuntu on the same machine, websites seem to take longer to start loading. I think the DNS lookup is slow. I think https sites may be slower, as I just can't log in to Gmail.

I am also using a mercurial repo with remote origin, and it takes forever (like 5 minutes) to push one small change. I think it is because it has to communicate through https multiple times. Should I change my DNS server? I've seen that I don't have these problems at my work network (they have another DNS server). This happens with the IPv4 settings being automatic (dhcp). When I change it to automatic (dhcp) addresses only, and add Google's 8.8.8.8 in the DNS servers, it still takes forever.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 5):

Is your router giving you an IPv6 address even though it doesn't have external connectivity? Run `ip addr` and see if there's a "scope global" inet6 address. If there is, what could be happening is that whatever browser you're using is attempting an IPv6 lookup first, which fails, and then falls back to IPv4.

The quick fix in Firefox is to go to `about:config` in the address bar, and search for `network.dns.disableipv6`, which you can then set to true. However, if this is the problem, you're better off looking at your router to see why it's giving the IPv6 address if it can't use it.

Comment: wow I believe this solved my issue, weird thing is I don't have this issue on any other browser and firefox on my windows 10 pc doesn't have this issue either.

Answer (score 0):

since your using wireless it could be cause the ubuntu drivers for your device suck or some settings need to be changed. Try to access something via IP address instead to see if the problem persists or connect to your switch using a cord.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth checking that your DNS server is getting set correctly. A very long time ago (2.2 Linux kernel) I found the default behaviour in the distro I was using at the time was to ignore the nameserver supplied via DHCP.

What nameserver gets setup under both OS? Have you verified that the details supplied in the DHCP response are getting used by the client? What timings do you get using dig/nslookup?

> I think https sites may be slower

That implies it's nothing to do with DNS.

Have you tried enabling / disabling the [TCP window scaling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_window_scale_option)?